Accessing NAS Drive from a node version > 16
Up until Node version 16, applications were able access a NAS Drive via SMB.
From v17 and up, SSL changes have essentially broken SMB2.
The nodejs.org site provided this explanation:
If you hit an ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED error in your application with Node.js 17, it’s likely that your application or a module you’re using is attempting to use an algorithm or key size which is no longer allowed by default with OpenSSL 3.0. A command-line option, --openssl-legacy-provider, has been added to revert to the legacy provider as a temporary workaround for these tightened restrictions.
The --openssl-legacy-provider option is not viable for our organization and I have not found a package that uses OpenSSL 3.0.
My questions:
Has anyone discovered an SMB package that uses OpenSSL 3.0 ?
Any suggestions would be gratefully welcomed.
I tried samba-client, but that requires and underlying smbclient installation.
I looked for SMB3 packages but found none.
I looked into nextcloud but that requires a nextcloud server.
